# htaccess redirect to seo friendly html

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

This is my htaccess

#

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cart-o-li-na/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|ttf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php?page=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^)page=(.*)($)
RewriteRule "^index\.php$" %1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

#

index.php has a base tag `<base href="https://www.example.com/cart-o-li-na"/>`.

My htaccess creates a valid html url
ex. https://www.example.com/cart-o-li-na/contatti.html
from
https://www.example.com/cart-o-li-na/index.php?page=contatti.html

but clicking the site menu, htaccess uses the url not coded in html.
it links directly to https://www.example.com/cart-o-li-na/index.php?page=contatti.html
without making it Seo Friendly

Comment: Why the OR flag for the first two conditions? You want to redirect if what was request is _neither_ an existing file or folder.

Comment: you are right. It should redirect to *.html in any case. I'm commenting these 2 conditions (#RewriteCond). But it is still not redirecting. Any Idea?

Comment: I think this is wrong in something
RewriteRule "^index\.php$" %1.html? [R=301,L]
this works
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean by the last paragraph in your question. Did you modify your HTML output accordingly, or do the links in there still contain the old URL structure?

Comment: I see that ***RewriteRule "^index\.php$" %1.html? [R=301,L]*** and ***RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]*** work perfectly alone but using them together gives me problems

Comment: the first redirect to an html page if used alone, but that page doesn't exist. the second let that page exist but the site does not redirect automatically

Comment: together it's a too many redirect